# SSRS Row Gropings Inverted (Export to Excel)

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services, grouping, ssrs-grouping

When i run my report my report in SSRS all groupings work correctly however when i export this report to excel the proper rows are grouped but the grouping is inverted (i.e. the last item in the grouping has the '+' sign instead of the parent, top row)

thanks for any help in this matter!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you read the following link and edit your question with more information we may be able to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS, when exporting to Excel, if the report item that controls whether another item is toggled is not in the previous or next row or column of the item being toggled, the outline is disabled also. See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd255234.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have your total added after the group rather than before.

(right click on the group and click add total before)

However, we really need more details/screenshots to see what the cause might be.

The drilldown in SSRS has more features than the grouping in Excel can handle so sometimes it is not possible to get in excel what you have in your report..